# Zoom in and zoom out a UIView from button position with animation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation

I want to open a `UIView` on button click and view should be popup from button's initial position to the while screen same as image gets open in gallery. On click image the image get open from the clicked position and covers the whole screen. I want the same behaviour with `UIView` on button click. I've tried below code:

Initial position:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.9, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
    self.vwDetails.frame = CGRect(x: self.btnSelectedVendor.frame.origin.x, y: self.btnSelectedVendor.frame.origin.y, width: self.btnSelectedVendor.frame.width, height: self.btnSelectedVendor.frame.height)
}, completion: nil)
```

On button click:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.9, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
    self.vwDetails.frame = CGRect(x: self.vwContainer.frame.origin.x, y: self.vwContainer.frame.origin.y, width: self.vwContainer.frame.width, height: self.vwContainer.frame.height)
}, completion: nil)
```

This code is not working for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
self.vwDetails.frame = CGRect(x: self.vwContainer.frame.origin.x, y: self.vwContainer.frame.origin.y, width: self.vwContainer.frame.width, height: self.vwContainer.frame.height)
```

Firstly you setup initial position

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.9, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
    self.vwDetails.frame = CGRect(x: self.vwContainer.frame.origin.x, y: self.vwContainer.frame.origin.y, width: self.vwContainer.frame.width, height: self.vwContainer.frame.height)
}, completion: nil)
```

and after you start animation

Answer (score 0):

To achieve both translation and scale at the same time, you'll want something like this:

```
let originalTransform = yourView.transform
let scaledTransform = originalTransform.scaledBy(x: 0.2, y: 0.2)
let scaledAndTranslatedTransform = scaledTransform.translatedBy(x: 0.0, y: -250.0)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
  self.main.transform = scaledAndTranslatedTransform
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Replace your code

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.9, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
    self.vwDetails.frame = CGRect(x: self.vwContainer.frame.origin.x, y: self.vwContainer.frame.origin.y, width: self.vwContainer.frame.width, height: self.vwContainer.frame.height)
}, completion: nil)
```

With this:

```
UIView.transition(with: self.vwContainer, duration:0.5, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
             self.vwContainer.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.vwContainer.frame.height)
            self.vwContainer.center = self.view.center
        }) { (b) in

        }
```

You can adjust the positioning according to your requirements